# How to update multiple fields using JsonResult and Ajax DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have JsonResult list of Articles  and it looked like this:

```
[
    {
        "tbl_dobavuvaci": null,
        "tbl_fakDet": null,
        "tbl_fakMas": null,
        "tbl_kompanii": null,
        "tbl_useri": null,
        "artID": 1,
        "artKompID": 1,
        "artUserID": 1,
        "artCode": 25456658845646540,
        "artIme": "Artikal 1 Ime",
        "artCenaNab": 10,
        "artCenaProd": 15,
        "artDDV": 18,
        "artDobavuvac": 1
    },
    {
        "tbl_dobavuvaci": null,
        "tbl_fakDet": null,
        "tbl_fakMas": null,
        "tbl_kompanii": null,
        "tbl_useri": null,
        "artID": 2,
        "artKompID": 1,
        "artUserID": 1,
        "artCode": 8606010872303,
        "artIme": "TestName",
        "artCenaNab": 25,
        "artCenaProd": 30,
        "artDDV": 18,
        "artDobavuvac": 1
    }
]
```

Now in HTML View i have javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/fakturi/getArticles", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                $('<option>',
                   {
                       value: data.artID,
                       text: data.artCode
                   }).html;        
            });
        })
        $(function () {
            $("[name='bar']").on("change", function () {
                $("#artikal").val($(this).val());   
            });
        });
    });
```

Now When i change `artCod` named dropdown with `artCode` values from Json, corectly updated second field with `artIme` name.

HTML CODE:

```
@Html.DropDownList("bar", null, string.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tbl_artikli, "", new { @class = "text-danger",})

@Html.DropDownList("artikal", null, string.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tbl_artikli, "", new { @class = "text-danger", })


 @Html.TextBox("artCenaProd", "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "artCenaProd", style = "width:60pt" })
```

My Question is how to update third field named `artCenaProd` when I will change dropdown?

Comment: What you mean by "When i change artCod named dropdown with artCode values from Json, corectly updated second field with artIme name.". The code you shared in the question seems to be incomplete/errory. Please post correct relevant code so people understand what you are trying to do

Comment: "how to update third field named artCenaProd" How to update what and where ?

Comment: On.change on Drodown list i need to update article name, and article price.  artCode is name of DropDown, it is article barcode list, and with this script which i use i can update just article name, and now i need to update this script to update article price also which is named artCenaProd on Json List. I thing now is clear ?

Comment: No. It is not clear ! Where you want to update the name and price ? What is the name/id of your dropdown ?

Comment: I have also HTML Code of course in my View page, ID and Name of Dropdown is **bar** and next i need to update form in HTML, if is needed i can upload also HTML Form code.

Comment: You still did not answer my question. Where you want to update ? What you want to update with  ? The json you posted does not have a property called Price! Please include the relevant code in question

Comment: **artCenaProd* is property for price, and also **artCenaProd** id id of field in HTML code, **bar** id ID of Dropdown list with values **artCode** from JSon, and Article Name is **artIme** in HTML Field also in JSON List value is same

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML element's you want to update.

Comment: I updated with HTML Code of the fields which i need to update on change **bar** dropdown, **artikal ** update corect with article name, now simply i need to update **artCenaProd** together when i choice barcode in **bar** dropdown, i need to update together article name (artikal) and ArticlePrice(artCenaProd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the json array you receive from your ajax call to a local variable in your script. When the dropdown change event is fired, read the selected option and get the option value (artID). Now filter the local array for items with this id and get the subset (If the artID's are unique, you will get a sub array with one it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var localData = [];
    var $bar = $("[name='bar']");

    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("/fakturi/getArticles")",
        function(data) {
            localData = data;
            $bar.empty();
            $.each(data,
                function(i, data) {
                    var t = $('<option>', { value: data.artID, text: data.artCode });
                    $bar.append(t);
                });
        });
    $bar.change(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();

        var filteredData = localData.filter(function(item) {
            return item.artID == v;
        });
        if (filteredData.length) {
            $("#artCenaProd").val(filteredData[0].artCenaProd);
        }

    });

});
```

Also if you are populating the Dropdown's options using the ajax call, no need to use the `DropDownList` helper method! Simply write HTML markup for a SELECT element

```
<SELECT name='bar'>

</SELECT>
```

Comment: I thing this is nearest answer, Now is problem just in dropdown list i see duplicated Barcodes. How to clear this ? Thank you

Comment: Json send just singular results, just your scrit for drpdown give me duplicated tesults. I can`t upload screenshoot at comment.

Comment: Do you already have data in your dropdown before the ajax code append options to that ? See my last para in the answer.

Comment: yes, with my first code which i give in question, data i had see correct, then was problem just price updating. first code update just article name, not updating price

Comment: I also trying with code from your last updated answer

Comment: call the `$bar.empty();` before the loop to clear existing items. But again, Do not load using the helper if you are loading via ajax.